# Warning: No port llvm found in the index

Tags: python, macos, numpy, installation, llvm

I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8. I am trying to install a particular library (bob toolbox from idiap). While installing the library I received an error

`--->  Computing dependencies for cctools
    --->  Building cctools
    Error: org.macports.build for port cctools returned: command execution failed
    Please see the log file for port cctools for details:
     /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_port s_devel_cctools/cctools/main.log
    Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1`

I further investigated and realized it was because of 

`Warning: No port llvm found in the index; can't rebuild`

I tried to install it via port install llvm-3.0 but it keeps on saying i dont have A file belonging to the `py26-matplotlib` (and many other `python26-numpy` files). I try to install `python26-numpy` and it says llvm not found. Looks like I am going in circles.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have gcc installed, following should work.

```
sudo port select python python27
sudo port clean llvm–3.0
sudo port install llvm–3.0 configure.compiler=gcc
```

Comment: When I try sudo port clean llvm–3.0, it gives me Error: Port llvm–3.0 not found. Then if I try with sudo port install llvm–3.0 configure.compiler=gcc, I get same answer. So I tried with sudo port install llvm–3.0. I see following: -->  Updating database of binaries: 0.0%
Warning: Error determining file type of `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/drv_libxml2.py': lstat(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/drv_libxml2.py):no such file or directory
Warning: A file belonging

Comment: (continued) to the `py26-libxml2` port is missing or unreadable. Consider reinstalling it.

Comment: @abhijitbendale Can you completely remove your python installation and reinstall ?